# JButton isn't visible until I Scroll over it

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, visible

I am just starting to make a simple mp3 player, I am creating the play, forward, back, etc... Button but for some reason only the first button appears and to make the second button appear I have to go and scroll over it. If you could help me fix that, that would be great. And I am using a two images one named play.jpg and another named next.png.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Graphic extends JPanel{

JFrame f = new JFrame();
JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

public Graphic(){

    gui();

}

public void gui(){

    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(1600,900);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(p);

    ppr(75,26,25,25,"pics/play.jpg");
    //above is the play button


    ppr(40,26,25,25,"pics/next.png");
// above is the button that wont appear until it is scrolled over (it is just to the      left of the button above



}

public void ppr(int x, int y, int width, int height, String file){
    p.setLayout(null);      

    Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image player = tool.getImage(file);
            ImageIcon playbutton = new ImageIcon(player);

    JButton play = new JButton(playbutton);
        play.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            p.add(play);

    // ********************** above is the the method that makes a button        


}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Graphic();

}



  }
```

Comment: to emphasise: *don't* do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever - instead use a suitable LayoutManager

Answer (score 1):

Run the GUI in a different thread, not the main thread.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

All UI code should be run in the event dispatch thread for Swing.

Comment: Clarify that answer. All UI code should be executed with in the Event Dispatching Thread

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `setBounds`. Use [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)
 you specified while initialising the panel and specify `GridBagConstraints`

Answer (score 1):

The `setVisible(true)` method should be invoked AFTER all the components have been added to the GUI.

I also agree with the other suggestions for better GUI design.

Comment: I agree. Past experimentation has led me to find that your answer is a  correct one. For some reason my first inclination was to comment about the design though. Also, I am not sure and cannot test it on my current machine but I believe running in the EDT will also fix the problem.

Comment: @KyleM, When you add components to a visible GUI you need to revalidate() the panel. Otherwise the panel size is (0, 0) so Swing thinks there is nothing to paint.